# Is DANE-EE TLSA version 3 (Domain-issued certificate from rfc6698) still supported in 2023?

Tags: tls, dane

I would like to setup a webserver using TLS without relying on third party CA.
Is it still possible in 2023 ?

FreeBSD was using the feature and is now using Let's Encrypt (as well as a lot of privacy-conscious projects)

Do you have an example of webserver using this technology now ?
Is this supported by all browsers ?

If not supported, is it possible to use another technology to provide TLS feature without relying on third party CA and still avoiding any warning on the client side ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this supported by all browsers ?

The [Wikipedia page for DANE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS-based_Authentication_of_Named_Entities#Applications) shows that DANE is not supported natively by any major browser.

> If not supported, is it possible to use another technology to provide TLS feature without relying on third party CA and still avoiding any warning on the client side ?

The only technology for server authentication supported by the majority of browsers is PKI using selected third-party CA.